# What are all the different ways in which we can refer to time in English?

Tags: tenses, time

I am trying to wrap my head around the ways in which we can refer to time in English. The following list is what I have been able to come up with:

1- Tense

2- Auxiliary constructions

3- Temporal adverbs

Am I missing anything? If not, is there fault in the above classification?